# How to change the back color for each 52 label in the same time

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

[image]

As you can in the picture, I want to make every time I click a chair (green square), I want to change the back color to brown and make the other chair gray. But the the thing is, it would be really tired to copy and paste the same codes over and over again to make it happen. I've been thinking of using loop, but I couldn't figure out how. Is there anyway to make a short code that can loop or anything that wouldn't need to copy and paste the same thing over and over again? Every seat has been renamed to (Seat1, Seat2, Seat3,..) makes me think that it would be possible to use loop?

Comment: Is this a Windows Forms application or a website?

Comment: @MartinParkin it's a Windows Form application

Comment: Just enumerate the controls in the `Controls` collection of your form.  If the control is a `Label` whose ID starts with `Seat` then you can change it's colour.

Comment: @MartinParkin sorry, but can you please explain it in details? Im quite new to vb.

Comment: Try to code the solution @Martin Parkin provided

Comment: If your seats are dragged onto a form, try the Martin Parkin solution.  Alternatively, create a Seat class, with properties such as _name, _position, _colour, _booked etc.  You can then use this class / a list(of Seat) to automatically build the seating arrangement.  Once this is done, you will be able to iterate through your seats and apply any function to whatever range of seats you like.

Comment: @NazhirinImran - The 'Seat's are labels?  When the Seat is clicked you want to change it's color to brown I understand, but then you say the other chair to gray.  What other chair?  Are the labels in any container, i.e. GroupBox?

Comment: I'd build my own collection of the target controls just to make things easier. FOR..EACH to do them all. The collection key would be the primary key of the data about the seat so you can quickly address the seat regardless of GUI name. I'd also set the control TAG the PK so a click would know which record to deal with.

Answer (score 1):

Create one handler for all the seats and when the form is shown hook the handler up to each of the seats.  I tested this using three seats.

```
Const numofSeats As Integer = 3 'change to reflect number of seats
Private Sub Form1_Shown(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Shown
    For x As Integer = 1 To numofSeats
        Dim lbl As Label = DirectCast(Me.Controls("Seat" & x.ToString), Label)
        lbl.BackColor = Color.Green
        AddHandler lbl.Click, AddressOf Seat_Click
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub Seat_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim lbl As Label = DirectCast(sender, Label)
    lbl.BackColor = Color.Brown
    '
    'Other? chair to gray?
    '
End Sub
```